# Problem of displaying addition and subtraction in decimal form on 2 Digits 7 segments in Proteus

Tags: proteus, 7segmentdisplay

I want to  finish an addition and subtraction circuit inside the Proteus program,
and display the sum and subtraction result in decimal on 7-segment displays, see below diagram.
The problem with my circuit is that it shows and counts as long as the result is below 9, but when I count the number above 9, it shows wrong.
I want the numbers on the 7 segments to be displayed only in decimal, not hex.
And I want my calculations to be done between the numbers 0 to 31 because I add two four-bit values and the sum of these two eventually reaches 31, and I want to do  subtraction as well.
My circuit  does addition and subtraction correctly, the only problem is displaying it.
See in the picture, I added a 2nd 9 to 9 and the result should be 18 and it shows 32, which is wrong.

[image: diagram of 4-bit adder/subtractor with 2-digit display]

[image: two 7-segment displays with hex inputs]

Comment: Why do you duplicate the lowest bit of the second displayed digit? If you would not have done that, the display would show "12" which, in Hex, is the sum of 9 and 9.

Comment: @StarCat No 4 bits above 9 and 4 bits below 9 and two 9s are added together and the result is 18 and the number 18 should be displayed on 7 pieces but this is not true. If you know the solution, help me, thank you

Comment: @Good There are BCD adders in the 7400 series: 74583 for example. Are you saying you are limited to just 7 devices (where an adder is considered one, each digit display is considered one, and each xor is considered one?) Also, I think you mean added 9 to 9 to get 18?

Comment: Is the “display” a Hex display (which I think is the case based on the circuit’s behavior), a BCD display or does it translate an 8-bit value into its decimal representation? The output of the LS83 adder is in binary and not in BCD as you seem to expect. And could you please explain why you duplicate the carry out bit.

Comment: @StarCat By entering two 4-bit numbers, my circuit performs sub and add operations and displays the result in 2 digit 7 segments. For example, I want to add the binary number 1111 with the binary number 1001. Display the numbers in decimal, but it does not work correctly. Did you understand the meaning?

Comment: @jonk Exactly, I want to see 18 with the addition of 9 to 9, but it shows 32

Comment: @Good And you must support subtraction, as well? Where is the sign of the result?

Comment: @jonk Look at the change section. If the logic state is 1, it subtracts, and if it is 0, it adds two 4-bit numbers.

Comment: @Good I know. That's NOT my question. (It's obvious.) I'm asking if that is a REQUIREMENT. And if it is a requirement then I'm asking "where's the result's sign?"

Comment: @jonk Yes, both addition and subtraction operations are required in the circuit

Comment: @Good without a sign in the display you cannot display negative results. Yet negative results are possible. Worse, you cannot with wire alone do binary to bcd conversion. I don't think I can be much use. There must be hidden information you have access to that I don't.

Comment: @jonk Regardless of what I said, if I want to display the binary number 00011111 on 2 7-segment numbers in decimal form, which can be 31, what should I do?

Comment: @Good I've written on the topic of excess 3 bcd conversion methods here. It requires parts. You have limitations that exclude them. So I'm stuck and cannot suggest a way. I do know for fact that it cannot be done with wiring.

Comment: @jonk Well, I have no other way, so please on one side we take 8 bits using Logic state and on the other side we see numbers on 2 numbers 7 segments facing the decimal and 2 digits. Thank you.

Comment: @Good Your digit displays do not expose each segment for individual access and control. Is that changing now? Not saying that helps much. Just curious.

Comment: @jonk I added the photo I want, look at the second image, you see, I entered the number 0000 1111 and it shows f, but I want the number 15 to be displayed instead of f.

Comment: @Good I'm pretty well aware of what you want. I'm just saying that what I understand of your scope and also you limitations means I'm not much help for you. All I can say is that there either is hidden information from me or else this is beyond what time allows me.

Comment: @jonk Can't you display f as 15?

Comment: @Good sure. Wire the high order bit to the upper digit and only two of the three remaining bits to the unit display. But that won't be helpful for other binary values. So no. Not generally. You need some more logic.

Comment: @jonk Can you draw for me?

Comment: @Good not laying in bed waiting to go to sleep using an app on a stupid cell phone. Just take your own last image in your post. Move the upper bit of F to the high order display, removing it from the low order display. Delete the middle bit of the remaining three so that 101 goes to the low order digit display instead of 111. But it is silly to do that. It just works in that one case.

Comment: @Good Look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUNJ5.png). It shows you how to modify your example so that the output shows "18" as the result. This is done with added logic you don't show. And it makes the point I want to make. The main point here is that you can do things well, but it will require more logic than you imagine.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting in binary. That means if you add 9 and 9 (you wrote "added 2 to 9", but from picture and expectation of 18, it seem you meant "added two nines") you get $$0001 \space 0010$$
which is 18 in binary and would be "12" in hexadecimal (Yours shows incorrectly 3, because you connected two bits together for whatever reason, so it reads 0011 instead of just 0001). Conversion to hex is easy, as each group of 4 bits refers to one digit in hex (0001 is 1, 0010 is 2). Converting to
decimal is not at all that simple (because 10 is not the power of two, its a pitty that we don't have 8 or 16 fingers, our life would be easier :D).

The only way of getting individual digits from binary numbers would be by dividing and modulo by 10. (0001 0010 = 18, 18/10 = 1, (18-1*10)%10 = 8) This would require using a microcontroller.

Alternative way is using BCD (binary coded decimal). That is way of representing decimal number in bits, by using 4 bits for each digit. For example 18 would be $$0001 \space1000$$ first part (0001) is 1, second (1000) is 8. each group of 4 bits ranges from 0000 to 1001 (=9).

This representation is what you would need. Unfortunately it is not that straightforward, because BCD no longer behaves as a mathematical number.
Imagine you incremented that number by one at a time: You start with $$0000\space 0000$$ next is $$0000\space 0001$$ this continues up to nine $$0000\space 1001$$
after adding one to nine, it would normally become $$0000\space 1010$$ which is 0 and 10, but you need it to become $$0001\space 0000$$ meaning 1 and 0 so 10. So you need the adding to overflow and carry bit at 1001 (9) instead of 1111 (15). This is called decimal correction.

A way to implement this would be: If the result is greater than 9, add additional 6 to make it owerflow and carry to next bit:$$0000\space 1010$$ is 10 in binary. Add 6 and it becomes$$0001\space 0000$$ which is 16 in binary, but 10 in BCD.

Your solution would be to find some adder that counts in BCD instead of binary. And connect the carry bit only to bit0 of the display, not bit0 and bit1 tied together, that makes no sense.